# What is the MongoDB equivalent of an UPDATE SQL which updates a record with existing field value

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this following SQL and I would like to know the MongoDB equivalent.

```
update tblName set kwatt = kwatt/3600000 where kwatt is not null.
```

**Note:**

I know we can write a JS function in the server and get this done, I want this to be done from PHP driver and I am not sure how can I do this easily.

Please help.

Comment: Note that there are two parts to this UPDATE: 1) update based on previous value. 2) update more than one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do it with both combining `findAndModify` and `stored javascript` together..

Create a stored function for division like ;

```
db.system.js.save({_id: "div",
             value: function (x, y) { return x/y; }});
```

Then in findAndModify something like ;

```
findAndModify({query:{id:1},update:{$set:{id:"div(this.id,5)"}}});
```

It's just for idea, I didnt test it..

[Stored Javascript Sample](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html)

Comment: This is interesting. I will test and get back to you.

Comment: This works, though there is no direct way to run `findAndModify()` in PHP, still you can get it from `$db->command()`.

Comment: yeap you're right, the only way to run findAndMofigy in PHP is $db->command()

Answer (score 1):

You can not perform this in one database operation. You need to query for the related rows first and then perform an additional update operation on each row. It is not possible
to update the value of a document with the value of a result row within one database operation. The rest is up to you and straight forward.

Comment: Not the answer I expect but looks like there is none ??? With some hope, still looking for it :D

Comment: Looking at the [MongoDB documentation for Updating](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) it kind of looks like this should be possible with use of the Modifier operations. However i can't test this out at the moment...